# First steps in WPF: how to fill in a cell in a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm coming from Delphi, Java, ..., and now I need to make my first WPF program.

I am making a program for reading and writing information to existing tables.

My idea is very simple:

- Create a grid and put it on the form
- Read the table:

  - First read the column names. Add those to the first cells of the grid (`var_Grid.Cells[0,i] = "Column_Name";`)
  - Second read all the data, currently in the table, and fill it in in the grid (`var_grid.Cells[i,j] = "data";`
- Do further processing

As I want to do some processing on my grid first, I would like to use a grid component, not linked to a database (so no `TDBGrid`, for the ones who know Delphi).

I quickly realised that WPF `Grid` is meant for adding components to a form (like a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`, for the Java programmers), so I thought opting for the `DataGrid` component.

However, when I check on [how to select a cell in a `DataGrid`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx): I see `DataGridCellInfo`, `ItemContainerGenerator`, `ContainerFromIndex`, ..., all that for just getting a cell? (There's even no code for entering data in that cell)

I believe the `DataGrid` is far too complicated, there must be a WPF visual component, which is far easier for filling up than that one, but searching on `Grid` in the toolbox gives no answers.

Does anybody know of an easier way to work with the WPF `DataGrid` or does anybody know of an easier component that does what I want?

**Edit after first comments**

I started with the `ListView` and the `GridView`. I managed quite rapidly getting a `GridViewColumn` working, but then I'm having the issue that I don't know the amount of columns I'll be having for the `ItemsSource` (I tried working with a `List<List<string>>` but that seemed to be too naïve :-)

**Second edit**
Apparently there's a mismatch between:

- what I would like to do, and:
- why I would like to do that.

What I would like to do, is create a grid of which, at runtime, I can define the amount of rows and columns and fill in the cells.

However, the discussion in the comments are flooded by the why I would like to do that.

So I would like to rephrase my question: is there a WPF visual grid component of which I can set and alter, at runtime, row and column number and fill in cell by cell?

If that grid component would have the possibility to have a header row, that would be nice.

Does anybody know about such a visual WPF component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [a ListView with a GridView](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/)? (Btw, this tutorial site is great for explaining all of the WPF Tools. AFAIK the Datagrid is so complicated, because it can virtualize and many other things...

Comment: Process data, Build a typed observablecollection of viewmodels from that. Bind to the itemssource of a datagrid. Don't use ui as a data store.

Comment: Could use a ListView with DataTemplate, if you show me what exactly you plan to do I can try and write an example for you.

Comment: I have started working with ListView and GridView, as you have mentioned. Filling in the titles of the columns was not a problem, but the table itself is not that simple.

Comment: @DarkTemplar: I don't think DataTemplate can be used: I have no idea what my tables will look like.

Comment: @Andy: I'm currently working in the more or less "direct" way (without MVVM), maybe it's an idea of my boss to make me feel the need of MVVM, just by letting me fail in case I don't use it :-)

Comment: I think that what you're trying to do is unclear. You stated that you're creating "a program for reading and writing information to existing tables....Read the table:..." but also stated " I would like to use a grid component, not linked to a database".  If not in a database, where do these "tables" that contain data exist? In a DataTable? Where is the data coming from? Images, drawings and/or code may be helpful.

Comment: @user9938: what I like to do, is reading the structure of a table (all the columns), and make the first row of a grid with those fields. Then I would like to do some processing with that grid (which might mean add new columns). If the link between the grid and the databse is too strong, some of those features won't be possible.

Comment: So you don't know the names, sizes and lengths of the grid in advance? So you can't create a DataModel and map/bind it to the GridLines.  This is only a suggestion (I haven't tried it myself, but that's the direction I would start googling in this case), but there is a `DataTable` class in .NET, which from what you describe could fit the usecase. Maybe it is possible to bind a DataTable to a Datagrid? Anyway, I'm just spitballing here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have gone fundamentally wrong way of implementation.
You want to directly manipulate the content of WPF UI elements.
But WPF is built on a very different concept.
The main way to get data in WPF is to use Data Context.
UI elements themselves get values ​​for their properties through Bindings.
By default, bindings use Data Context as the source.

Therefore, for the correct implementation, you must first create an entity that will provide Data for one DataGrid row in its properties.
Then create an observable collection with these entities.
And bind this collection to DataGrid.ItemsSource.

The DataGrid will automatically create a column for each property of the entity and display the property value in it.
If you wish, you can customize the desired view of DataGrid and its cells yourself.

Thus, your task will be reduced to working with the collection and its elements, instead of a rather complex search inside the DataGrid and its visual tree.

One of the universal sources for a DataGrid can be a DataTable.
This type should be used when you cannot predefine all the required properties for an entity of one row.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there are many ways to go about implementing data content display in a form, via DataGrid, ListView, etc.  By going the MVVM pattern, your Model is obviously the data source where things will come from, and be stored to, such as a SQL database of some type, Excel via OleDbConnection connectivity, etc.

The ViewModel is the core that implements all your how do I get the data and how do I save the data, but also expose button click actions, validations for user input, etc.  Your ViewModel becomes the "DataContext" for the binding source baseline for your Views.  You expose the actual data via making properties public via getter/setter such as

```
public DataTable MyListOfCustomers {get; set;}
```

Then, somewhere in your view model, you run your query to do nothing but load the records into this data table object.

The View is obviously the what you are displaying to the end-user.  This is what is unclear by the brief and otherwise ambiguous explanation in your post.  In almost any application, you may have many datagrids representing data for many different things, but those datagrids will typically always represent the same content.  For example a customer screen would always be showing a list of customers and allow search, sort, specific columns, etc.  An inventory screen would always show items available, etc.

So, when doing an app, instead of relying on how can I make it always dynamically available, it might be best to define each visual datagrid component on its own, so its always the same and based on a known source.  Then, just add that one user control into your view where you need it.  If anything needs to be changed on that one datagrid, change it once, and any other view using it gets the same impact applied.

Having said all that, and the bindings themselves are pretty simple, you might want to edit your post, not via comments which are limited. Post a little more explicit context of what you are trying to do.  Types of actual data being presented.  Its not like you are doing something so brand-new and top secret that you cant disclose.  But maybe an overall context of the TYPE of work this system will have.  Will it be accounting based doing numbers (or even stock sales based), inventory systems, etc.  Will this one datagrid be changing of content being displayed within itself, or will it be more like I described that each secondary view or even child area within a single view be showing different datagrid content.

Offering vague information, even coming from another development arena will not fend well for you when looking for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to modify the columns of a `DataGrid` dynamically, you should choose the `DataTable` as data model for the grid.

Note that adding/removing columns requires to update each row in order to provide a value for the new column, which can have noticeable impact on the performance depending on the size of the table model (number of rows in particular).
In this case you should implement data virtualization. You would track the viewport i.e. the current items in view and update pending row data changes as necessary.

### Example

This is a very basic example to show how to make modifications to the columns of a `DataGrid` at runtime with the help of the [`DataTable` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0#examples).

The example makes use of data binding (which drastically simplifies the logic) and commanding:

- [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0)
- [Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Additionally, the example relies on column auto generation of the `DataGrid` (this feature is enabled by default) - otherwise the complexity of the solution would increase, of course. Without auto column generation you would have to add (simple) logic to the view.

**MainViewModel.cs**
This class uses a `RelayCommand`. You can find an example implementation at [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.TableData = new DataTable();
    AddColumn<int>("ID");
    AddColumn<string>("Username");
    AddColumn<string>("Mail");

    AddRow(1, "Me", "me@mail.com");
  }

  private void AddColumn<TColumnData>(string columnName, int columnIndex = -1)
  {
    var newColumn = new DataColumn(columnName, typeof(TColumnData));    
    this.TableData.Columns.Add(newColumn);
    if (columnIndex > -1)
    {
      newColumn.SetOrdinal(columnIndex);
    }

    int newColumnIndex = this.TableData.Columns.IndexOf(newColumn);

    // Initialize existing rows with a default value for the new column.
    // In this example the default value of the column's data type is used.
    foreach (DataRow row in this.TableData.Rows)
    {
      row[newColumnIndex] = default(TColumnData);
    }
  }

  // Ensure that column values are ordered by their column's index
  private void AddRow(params object[] columnValues)
  {
    DataRow rowModelWithCurrentColumns = this.TableData.NewRow();
    this.TableData.Rows.Add(rowModelWithCurrentColumns);

    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < this.TableData.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
      rowModelWithCurrentColumns[columnIndex] = columnValues[columnIndex];
    }
  }

  // Force the binding target (DataGrid) to create new column templates 
  // by changing the binding source instance
  private void OnDataTableColumnsChanged() => this.TableData = this.TableData.DefaultView.ToTable();

  // Add columns dynamically via an ICommand
  public ICommand AddColumnCommand => new RelayCommand(commandParameter =>
  {
    AddColumn<DateTime>($"Timestamp {this.TableData.Columns.Count}");
    OnDataTableColumnsChanged();
  });

  public ICommand AddRowCommand => new RelayCommand(commandParameter => AddRow(2, "You", "you@mail.com", DateTime.Now));

  private DataTable tableData;
  public DataTable TableData
  {
    get => this.tableData;
    set
    {
      this.tableData = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  /*** Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged ***/

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Remarks**:

Alternatively, the members `AddColumn` and `AddRow` can be implemented as extension methods.

You can call `AddColumn` and `AddRow` from any caller - not only from an `ICommand`. Just make sure to call `OnDataTableColumnsChanged` to promote the column changes to the view after all columns have been added/removed.
In the view, rows don't require the creation of any view templates, therefore those row data changes are immediately visible. How a row's cell is rendered is defined in the column's template.
View columns on the other hand require a view template to tell the `DataGrid` how to render the column and its cell. Calling `OnDataTableColumnsChanged` forces the binding target (the `DataGrid`) to generate the column templates for the new columns.
In case the data source of the `DataTable` is actually a database, a new instance of `DataTable` would be created after each query, which would make a call to `OnDataTableColumnsChanged` redundant.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>

    <!-- Don't forget to qualify the type with the defined XAML namespace (xmlns) -->
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add Column" Command="{Binding AddColumnCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Add Row" Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```